# Unable to install TVHeadEnd PVR client - Missing PVR Clients add-ons section in Kodi

Tags: pi-4, raspbian-buster, kodi

I have followed theese quides:

[how-to-stream-digital-tv](https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/how-to-stream-digital-tv-with-the-raspberry-pi-tv-hat)

[Kodi on Raspberry Pi OS / Raspbian Buster](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=251645)

Installed KODI on RPI 4B. Also have installed working TVHeadend server.
But cannot get [Tvheadend_HTSP_Client](https://kodi.wiki/view/Add-on:Tvheadend_HTSP_Client) working.

I have also tried to install it using `sudo apt`.
Still I do not see it among add-ons and no other PVR clients either. The PVR add-on section is missing.
In System Information in KODI is PVR greyed out.
Seems it is disabled somehow, how to enable it?

> No PVR add-on enabled

There are [some workarounds for older versions](https://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=347445) that do not work for me either.

I tried it before using SD card with LibreELEC and I had to install it in Kodi from LibreELEC repository, but it worked then. But I cannot use LibreELEC repository in Kodi on Buster, right?

Answer (score 0):

It was just that I missed the menu items:

```
Add-ons -->  My add-ons -> PVR Clients
```

It was there and finally I was able to enable the TVHeadend HTSP Client.

It was already there because I have installed it using

```
sudo apt-get install kodi-pvr-tvheadend-hts
```